# How come Heroku PHP buildpack's Apache is using almost no memory

Tags: apache-2.4, heroku

When using Heroku's PHP buildpack, I check `ps aux`:

```
23438    25568  0.0  0.0 119600    48 ?        Ss   Feb06   0:32 httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/apache2/heroku.conf
23438    25569  0.0  0.0 867316   276 ?        Sl   Feb06   2:13 httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/apache2/heroku.conf
23438    25570  0.0  0.0 867316     0 ?        Sl   Feb06   2:13 httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/apache2/heroku.conf
23438    25571  0.0  0.2 867316  1160 ?        Sl   Feb06   2:13 httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/apache2/heroku.conf
```

The httpd is using almost 0 memory which is good and which I want to achieve. Their configs are here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/bd3e49808b0889c1f9f2a582d8b9ccdb8c4f60db/conf/apache2/httpd.conf.default but it's pretty standard. When I use the same config on my Docker image with Apache compiled from source and php working via php-fpm, my httpd process uses more memory

```
root      2391  0.0  1.4 119624  7400 ?        Ss   17:08   0:00 /app/.my/php/sbin/httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/.my/config/my.conf
www-data  2464  0.0  0.9 408588  4880 ?        Sl   17:08   0:00 /app/.my/php/sbin/httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/.my/config/my.conf
www-data  2465  0.0  0.9 408588  4880 ?        Sl   17:08   0:00 /app/.my/php/sbin/httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/.my/config/my.conf
www-data  2466  0.0  0.9 408588  4880 ?        Sl   17:08   0:00 /app/.my/php/sbin/httpd -D NO_DETACH -c Include /app/.my/config/my.conf
```

And I don't think it's anything to do with php, because I have another image where php is served via mod_php and it is the same:

```
root     27661  0.0  0.0   4448     0 ?        S    Feb07   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND
root     27663  0.0  0.0 248692   216 ?        S    Feb07   0:29 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
www-data 27664  0.0  1.0 1056472 5312 ?        Sl   Feb07   2:15 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
www-data 27665  0.0  1.1 1056472 5688 ?        Sl   Feb07   2:15 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
www-data 27666  0.0  1.1 1056472 5552 ?        Sl   Feb07   2:14 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: Are you running the event MPM? That's what Heroku uses.

Comment: yeah I am, copied the build script and config...